# Passing JavaScript values to PHP file using XHR call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a PHP file on a server that needs to take dynamic values from client-side use on a web page in order to query my database. The user will click a link which (as well as directing the user to a new tab) takes the document location string that the link is connected to. I am currently trying to pass these values to the server side code using jQuery/AJAX and an XHR call, but when I run it, it seems that the PHP does not execute properly. Here is the JavaScript code:

```
// Clicking the link
$('a.docs').on('click', function(){

    // Getting the values needed for the query from existing table
    var theData = subtable.row($(this).parents('tr')).data();

    // The document string
    var thedoc = theData[7];

    // Pass the document value to the PHP file on the server
    $.post('https://example.com/TEST/dashboard/change.php', {
        document: thedoc
    });

    // Make XHR call to execute the PHP file on the server
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", "https://example.com/TEST/dashboard/change.php", true);
    xhr.send();
});
```

As you can see, I try to send the value of `thedoc` to the file on the server before making the `GET` XHR call. Here is the what PHP code on the server does:

```
<?php
    // The line that grabs the document variable being passed
    $document = $_POST['document'];

    // ... MySQL query stuff using $document as parameter...
?>
```

When I test this and click the link on the webpage, the JavaScript correctly grabs the document link variable, it's just the passing that has not been working. Any ideas on what I am doing incorrectly?

Comment: The `$.post` call should have the document on your server-side. Have you tried to `console.log` `thedoc` variable?

Comment: Yes and it is grabbing the correct variable that I need to pass to the PHP

Comment: Well your PHP script should be being called twice. First when you do the `$.post` call and another time in the xhr. The first should send the value to the server, the second shouldn't. Try removing the XHR call because it doesn't make sense.

Comment: That could be what's happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot comment :(

I agree with jorgonor1.

You are performing **2 separate** requests to your server.

The first. You are sending data to the server with JQUERY in the section $.POST(...). And from the sample code, ignore the results.

Then secondly, you perform a clean request of the generic page with the xhr request.

If you use $.POST(), and want to perform something with the result from the server try:

```
    $.post('https://example.com/TEST/dashboard/change.php', {document: thedoc}, function(result){
//do something with the data returned form the server, server response stored in "result" variable
});
```

See the example on [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_post.asp)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use jQuery, just try

```
let data = form.serialize();
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

or if you want to use xhr, you need to send the data as key/value pair string:

```
let data = "document=thedoc"
```

Comment: In your jQuery example, would `thedoc` go into `data` or `dataType`